# C# SqlReader issue

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, list

I'am posting on this forum for the first time . and I really hope I can find some help .
What I'am doing is load about ... 1000 Value (example) from **SQL** and I'am doing it just fine .

the query for example is : `Select Value from DatabaseA.dbo.Values`

that "Value" ==> decimal(10, 2)

```
sqlConnection2.Open();
insertCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader reader2 = insertCommand2.ExecuteReader();
if (reader2.HasRows)
{
  while (reader2.Read())
  {
    decimal Value = reader.GetDecimal(0);
```

this propably should work fine . but What I want to do is to make + on all of them ... 
For example first value = 16 , second = 28 , third : 78

I want to make 16 + 28 + 78 ... but for all Values that Loaded them . 
How Can I do that please ? , thanks .

Comment: The code makes no sense. You show us a `SELECT` query but you're using `ExecuteNonQuery`, then you're using `ExecuteReader` on the same command to get a `SqlDataReader reader2` but you're using `reader` later which you haven't shown at all.

Comment: Are you saying you want a total sum or a running total? Ie if the rows are `10/12/10` would you like just `32` or `10/22/32`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the original values as well, you could have a `List<decimal>` and accumulate the totals.

```
List<decimal> totals = new List<decimal>();
```

Then in your while loop:

```
totals.Add(Value);
```

You can then return the running total via:

```
var runningTotal = totals.Sum();
```

If you do not want the original values, you can just use:

```
 decimal value;
 while (reader2.Read())
 {
    value += reader.GetDecimal(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take your variable outside of your loop and use the [+= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

```
decimal Value = 0;
sqlConnection2.Open();
insertCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader reader2 = insertCommand2.ExecuteReader();

if (reader2.HasRows)
{
    while (reader2.Read())
    {
       Value += reader.GetDecimal(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change sql as

```
Select Sum(Value) from DatabaseA.dbo.Values
```

and then

```
decimal Value = (decimal)insertCommand2.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL `SUM` function. Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx